# WSL2: port-forwarding between Windows and Linux

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'd like to set up port-forwarding on my laptop between windows and my ubuntu instance of WSL2.  My intent is that certain ports, when listening inside Ubuntu, are accessible via `localhost` on the windows machine.  The point is to be able to access these tools via the browser over `localhost`, rather than needing `wsl hostname -I`.

My application is configured to redirect the user to `localhost` when run locally in certain cases, which is obviously a flaw, but it is what it is for now.

I've tried running

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8080 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=8080 connectaddress=$($(wsl hostname -I).Trim());
```

Followed by opening the firewall for that port with

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "WSL2 Port Bridge" -Direction Inbound -Action Allow -Protocol TCP -LocalPort 8080
```

But that did not create the link I'm looking for. I still cant access an app running on port 8080 inside WSL via the browser with `localhost:8080`

Answer (score 1):

Figured out my problem.  I had another process running on Windows that was listening on port 8080.  Apparently this set up won't prevent WSL from opening a port that is already open on Windows, it will just silently not be accessible.

Once I killed the other process, it works.

Comment: Correct and good work.   WSL already exposes it's ports automatically to the host machine as localhost:nnn but if the host already uses same ports the WSL process won't fail because of it.   This is sensible since technically WSL is an independent "complete" machine on it's own (at least it tries to act as such) but with integrations into the host.   You should accept your own answer as complete to close out the question.